# running ruby-sass-compass, how to close terminal

Tags: ruby, terminal, sublimetext2, compass-sass

I'm new to terminal and ruby and sass and compass. I'm a first time user. I've gotten command line down to where I can use compass watch to update my .scss file in the Drupal Zen subtheme I'm working with. Now I've discovered an extension for my Sublime Text 2  called SublimeOnSaveBuild which seems to do the same thing. Now I want to close terminal and I get a warning, "Closing this window will terminate the running processes: ruby." Should I go ahead and close it or will that mess me up for using ST2 or Terminal later?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can close Terminal if you want. SublimeOnSaveBuild will compile your files every time you save, eliminating the need for Compass (run by ruby) to watch the files.

Comment: turns out when I closed Terminal, my SublimeOnSaveBuild stopped working, so perhaps it was never working to begin with. Any tips on troubleshooting?

Comment: you need to have a working [build system](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html) for compass, and you need to have the directory containing your `.scss` files and `config.rb` file in a Sublime [project](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html). I'd recommend trying out the [`Compass`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Compass) package for the build system. You'll need to install [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) (very highly recommended) first, though. (continued)

Comment: Once you can edit a `.scss` file, save it, and build it with `Command-B`, then SublimeBuildOnSave will work. In the meantime, you can disable it: open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> SublimeOnSaveBuild -> Settings-Default` and `Settings-User`. Copy the entire contents of `Default` to `User`, then change `"build_on_save"` to `0`. Save the file, and the plugin will be disabled for now. Just remember to set it back to `1` once your build system is working.

Comment: It still appears not to be working. On save or build I get an error at the bottom (the console?):
LoadError on line ["45"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- zen-grids
Run with --trace to see the full backtrace

Any idea what that's about?

Comment: Compiling now with Terminal gives me same error so now I can't compile at all.